# Error adding ChromiumWebBrowser to project - C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to add the Cef.WinForms library to my project and I'm following the steps found here
https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/DEVELOPING-CHROMIUM-BASED-BROWSER-IN-Csharp/1468.  I was able to add the library find using Nuget, however I did get a warning that it expected .NET 4.6.1 and I have .NET 5.0.  I tried to manually install 4.6.1 but it will not allow it as it says a newer version is already installed.  This may not even be the cause of my error but I wanted to mention it just in case.

When I try to drag the component ChromiumWebBrowser over to my main form, I get the error seen below.  I've searched for this error to try and resolve it but I am so far not finding anything helpful.  Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

[image]

Comment: I used to get similar design time errors when using controls targeting a different architecture (x86 or x64). Try switching your target architecture for design time (x86 or x64 instead of Any CPU)

Comment: @Fixation that's just using the Configuration Manager right?  I have tried Any CPU, x86 and x64 from the main toolbar to the right of "Debug" and "Release" dropdown.

Comment: Did you install the correct NuGet package for .NET 5.0? You need the CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore package

Comment: @Fixation that was totally it.  I did not have that package installed.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, when targeting `.Net 5.0` you'll need to use the packages with the **NETCore** suffix.

For `.Net Core 3.1/.Net 5.0+`

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore/

**NOTE** A minimum of `.Net Core 3.1` is required.

For the `.Net 4.5.2` to `.Net 4.8`

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/

---

All packages require **[Microsoft Visual C++ 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022) or greater.**

**Ijwhost.dll**

To support C++/CLI libraries in .NET Core/.Net 5+, ijwhost was created by Microsoft as a shim for finding and loading the runtime. All C++/CLI libraries are linked to this shim, such that ijwhost.dll is found/loaded when the C++/CLI library is loaded. It's important this dll is distributed with your application.